# Prove that C is a basis for F

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

The question is as follows:

*Let **C** be a set of vectors in a vector space **F** with the property that every vector in **F** can be written uniquely as a linear combination of the vectors in **C**. Prove that **C** is a basis for **F**.*

The question seems simple enough and I know that the vectors in C are linearly independent but i always have trouble actually formulating the proof onto a piece of paper. Can someone get me started in the right direction?   Am i to show that C is linearly independent and spans the vector space?

Comment: Yeah, write out the definition of a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to show that $C$ is linearly independent and spans $F$.

That every vector in $F$ can be written  as a linear combination of the vectors in $C$ shows that $C$ spans $F$.

Now take $c_1,....,c_n \in C$ and let $t_1,....,t_n $ be scalars such that

$0=t_1c_1+....+t_nc_n$.

You have to show that it results that $t_1=....=t_n=0$

Comment: How would i show that t_1 = ... = t_n =0? The problem seems so intuitive but all the technicalities always bog me down. It would just appear that all the vectors of C are linearly independent because they span F

Comment: You have to use: "...every vector in $F$ can be written uniquely as a linear combination of the vectors in $C$...". We have $0=t_1c_1+....+t_nc_n$ and(!) $0=0c_1+....+0c_n$ ! Your turn !